# Swift Dictionary - Update value in setter function

Tags: swift, dictionary

My code looks a little like:

**Protocol**

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    var featureConfigs: [String: Any]? { get set } 
}
```

**Base Class**

```
class MyBaseClass: MyProtocol {
    var featureConfigs: [String : Any]? {
        get {
            return nil
        }
        set {
            self.featureConfigs = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

**Subclass**

```
class MySubclass: MyBaseClass {
    override var featureConfigs: [String : Any]? {
        get {
            return ["feature-specific-configuration":""]
        }
        set {
            self.featureConfigs = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to update the values stored in `featuresConfig`. I understand that doing `self.featureConfigs = newValue` causes an infinite loop but I am unsure of how to update the `featuresConfig` dictionary correctly. I've read about and tried some things with `Subscript` but I couldn't get that to work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably want to make your `featureConfigs` a stored property in your base class instead of a calculated one, using `didSet` or `willSet` to observe changes. How exactly do you want the subclass to behave though?

Comment: I guess that is an option I should try! I want the subclass to update a particular key in the dictionary with the updated value. Thats all it needs to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to set a persistent value for your `featureConfigs`, it needs to be a stored property, rather than a calculated one (this could also be a private backing variable that you create for this task, as [@AMomchilov says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37661847/2976878)). You can then use `willSet` or `didSet` to observe changes.

In your subclass, you can override the stored property declaration with a calculated one in order to allow you to update a given value-key pair in the dictionary when it's accessed, using `super` in order to refer to the superclass's stored property.

For example:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    var featureConfigs: [String: Any]? { get set }
}


class MyBaseClass: MyProtocol {
    var featureConfigs: [String : Any]? { // stored property with setter observers
        willSet {
            print("about to be set")
        }
        didSet {
            print("was set")
        }
    }
}


class MySubclass: MyBaseClass {
    // calculated property that forwards to super's stored property
    override var featureConfigs: [String : Any]? {
        get {
            // injects the updated value of a given key when accessing
            guard var config = super.featureConfigs else {return nil}
            config["feature-specific-configuration"] = "baz"
            return config
        }
        set {
            super.featureConfigs = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

```
let s = MySubclass()

s.featureConfigs = ["foo":"bar"]
print(s.featureConfigs) // Optional(["feature-specific-configuration": "baz", "foo": "bar"])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is a [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259). Unlike [stored properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255), it's not backed by a persistent instance variable.

You can manually create a private instance variable to back the storage of this psuedo-computed-property. You can then give this variable a default value specific to the subclass it belongs to.